# Apply a second function if the first one fails

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to Pandas and Numpy. I have a dataframe with which I would like to create a new column by applying a function to each row of a column. Let's take a simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["names"], data=["Brussels", 2, "New York"])

def to_lower(value):
    try:
        return value.lower()
    except AttributeError:
        return None

def to_string(value):
    return str(value)

df['lower_names'] = np.vectorize(to_lower)(df['names'])
```

This operation works very well. Now I would like to apply the `to_string()` then the `to_lower()` only for the lines of "lower_names" where the result is None (I do not know if this is very clear).

This seems very basic, and yet I have trouble. I could detail my attempts, but I am afraid of appearing a moron... Maybe I should bother to learn these two modules one week or two before playing around with them, but in the meantime, any suggestion would be welcome.

Edit : the @jezrael solution is correct... for my simplified example. Now let's imagine that I want to apply the `np.vectorize(to_string)` function and then `np.vectorize(to_lower)` only on the rows of the column "names" where the first result is None, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need change `return None` to `return to_string(value)`:

```
def to_lower(value):
    try:
        return value.lower()
    except AttributeError:
        return to_string(value)

def to_string(value):
    return str(value)

df['lower_names'] = np.vectorize(to_lower)(df['names'])


print (df['lower_names'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
Name: lower_names, dtype: object
```

Also is possible use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for convert all values to `str` and then [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html):

```
df['lower_names'] = df['names'].astype(str).str.lower()
```

Comment: Thank you, @jezrael, that was part of my attempts. It works very well on my simplified example, but not on my actual data and I don't know why... Meanwhile, simplifying the problem to post it on SO helps me a lot clarify my own reflexion.

Comment: @EttoreRizza - I believe so. Try some debugging or try explain more what is problem.

Comment: You are right, of course, I asked a wrong question by simplifying it too much. I will edit it, and accept your answer if no other one answers more accurately to the problem that I wrongly defined.

Comment: Hmm, `then np.vectorize(to_lower) only on the None` are you sure? need replace `None` by `string` `None` ?

Comment: I am a bit confuesd, because if use `apply the np.vectorize(to_string)` there is no `None` only all values are converted to strings

Comment: I'm sorry, it's because the example I gave is always solvable by applying `to_string()`when `to_lower ()` failed. In my real case, the None can represent several values. This is why I can not just use to_string()``  inside of to_lower() (I get the impression that my explanations become more confusing every time I try to specify them)

Comment: Yes, good sample is hard, I understand. Maybe the best is change sample and desired output, what do you think?